# Nicotine+ crashes on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

A soon as I launch Nicotine Plus it crashes. I didn't have this problem ever before with Ubuntu 16.04 or 16.10 and it also worked fine after I installed 17.04 two weeks ago. I uninstalled it and re-installed many times from the Software Center, tried using a .deb file etc but can't get it to work. Could anyone help?

Comment: Could you please try to rename the `~/.nicotine` directory with the per-user configuration and try to run the application again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same same problem and fixed it by:

1. Uninstalling `nicotine-plus`
2. Deleting the `.nicotine` folder (notice the `.`) from my home directory
3. Reinstalling `nicotine-plus` again

And voilà, it's running again!

Comment: Step 2 probably would have been enough.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I actually installed SoulseekQt for LInux which is much better in my opinion, at least as far as search results are concerned.